# How many ten letter words are there with no repeated letters that contain neither the word ERGO nor the word LATER?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many ten letter words are there with no repeated letters that contain neither the word ERGO nor the word LATER?

I am thinking that there are 26^10 words with ten letters and 26P10 10 letter words with repeated lettes.

So I would begin by taking 26^10 - 26P10, but not sure how to subtract the words containing ERGO or LATER.  Also not sure what to add to the end to account for the words that repeat and contain ERGO, the words that repeat and contain LATER, the words that contain ERGO and LATER, and the words that contain repeated letters and contain ERGO and LATER.

Comment: What does "contain" mean specifically in this case? Can the letters appear in any order anywhere in the word, or does the word specifically have to contain the letters in a row, in order, in the word?

Comment: the words ERGO and LATER must be in order and in a row

Comment: In the case of ERGO, since the letters cannot repeat, and you can't use the letters 'ERGO', its equivalent to finding the number of 6-letter words containing none of the letters E,R,G or O (a 22-letter alphabet), multiplied by the number of ways you can arrange ERGO between the 6 letters. There are $P(22,6)$ ways to select the other 6 letters, and 7 ways to arrange ERGO between them.

Comment: use inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Given an alphabet of $n$ letters one can form $$n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)={n!\over (n-r)!}$$ words of length $r$ using no letter twice.

It follows that there are ${26!\over16!}$ such words of length $10$ from the English alphabet.

There are ${22!\over16!}$ such words of length $6$ not using the letters occurring in ERGO. Each of these words has $7$ spaces (including the ends) where you can insert ERGO.

There are ${21!\over16!}$ such words of length $5$ not using the letters occurring in LATER. Each of these words has $6$ spaces (including the ends) where you can insert LATER.

There are ${19!\over16!}$ such words of length $3$ not using the letters occurring in LATERGO. Each of these words has $4$ spaces (including the ends) where you can insert LATERGO.

Apart from the words containing LATERGO there are no $10$-letter words using no letter twice and containing ERGO as well as LATER.

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle we therefore obtain the following number of words containing no letter twice and not containing ERGO or LATER:
$${26!\over16!}-{22!\over16!}\cdot 7-{21!\over16!}\cdot 6+{19!\over16!}\cdot 4=19\,274\,833\,290\,456\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

all words with no repetetion: $P\left( 26,10 \right)$

words including ERGO: forms are like  (ERGO_ _ _ _ _ _ ) or (_ _ ERGO _ _ _ _ )

$P\left( 22,6 \right)\cdot 7$ words.

words including LATER: similarly

$P\left( 21,5 \right)\cdot 6$ words.

including both: ERGOLATER_

$P\left( 3,3 \right)$ words.

now use inclusion-exclusion principle

$P\left( 26,10 \right)-\left[ P\left( 22,6 \right)\cdot 7+P\left( 21,5 \right)\cdot 6\text{ }\!\!~\!\!\text{ } \right]+P\left( 3,3 \right)$

Comment: You are double-counting words that contain ERGO twice, or LATER twice.

Comment: TonyK is right: `ERGOZZERGO` is included twice in your count $P(22,6)\cdot 7$.

Comment: but letters wasn't allowed to be repeated. your word has repetetions. but i noticed where i'm wrong now.

Comment: Its not possible to have ERGO or LATER appear twice in a word - they would be repeated. Likewise, ERGOLATERXY could not occur because the E and R would also be repeated. At best you could have LATERGOXYZ.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry! But on the same basis, ERGOLATER_ is also forbidden.